# How does stringvar work with textvariable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, var

I am writing a chess program and I can't get the pieces to output since I changed the text from being defined with text to text variable and now I can't get string working to output the pieces. 
I define the buttons in a for loop and it outputs nothing in the squares. The code is

```py
def drawboard(self):

        x=0
        y=0
        for column in range(self.n):
            self.changecolours()
            x=x+1
            y=0
            for row in range(self.n):
                y=y+1
                colour = self.colours[self.colourindex]
                pos=(x,9-y)
                buttons=(tk.Button(self.boardframe, padx=10,  textvariable=lambda position=pos: self.placepieces(position), borderwidth=0, bg=colour,  relief="solid", font=self.piecefont, command=lambda position=pos: self.movepiece(position)  ))
                buttons.grid(column=(x-1), row=(y-1), sticky="W"+"E"+"N"+"S" )
                self.changecolours()
    @classmethod
    def placepieces(cls, position):
        black=Black()
        white=White()
        squareposition=position
        icon=tk.Stringvar("")
        if squareposition in white.position.values():
            for key in white.position:
                value=white.position.get(key)
                if value==squareposition:
                    if key.endswith("pawn"):
                        icon.set(white.pawntype[key])
                    elif key=="king":
                        icon.set(white.PIECES.get("KING"))
                    elif key=="queen":
                        icon.set(white.PIECES.get("QUEEN"))
                    elif key.endswith("bishop"):
                        icon.set(white.PIECES.get("BISHOP"))
                    elif key.endswith("knight"):
                        icon.set(white.PIECES.get("KNIGHT"))
                    else:
                        icon.set(white.PIECES.get("ROOK"))


                else:
                    pass
        elif squareposition in black.position.values():
            for key in black.position:
                value=black.position.get(key)
                if value==squareposition:
                    if key.endswith("pawn"):
                        icon.set(black.pawntype.get(key))
                    elif key=="king":
                        icon.set(black.PIECES.get("KING"))
                    elif key=="queen":
                        icon.set(black.PIECES.get("QUEEN"))
                    elif key.endswith("bishop"):
                        icon.set(black.PIECES.get("BISHOP"))
                    elif key.endswith("knight"):
                        icon.set(black.PIECES.get("KNIGHT"))
                    else:
                        icon.set(black.PIECES.get("ROOK"))                 
                    break

                else:
                    pass
        else:
            icon.set("")
        return icon
```

Comment: All of the the `...variable=` options in Tkinter absolutely require one of the Tkinter Var types: `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.  They *cannot* be a lambda or any other Python object whatsoever.

Comment: The lambda is there to store the coordinate of the square. If I can't do this using lambda how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does stringvar work with textvariable?

In the case of a Button, you can configure the text to be displayed in one of two ways: with a hard-coded string (eg: `text='click me'`) or with the `textvariable` attribute.

The `textvariable` attribute must be set to an instance of one of the special tkinter variable objects `StringVar`, `IntVar`, `DoubleVar` or `BooleanVar` (eg: `var=tk.StringVar(); Button(..., textvariable=var)`). When configured with an instance of one of these variables, the text on the button will display whatever the value of the variable is.

Internally, when you specify a `textvariable`, tkinter will take the string representation of that object and create a tcl variable in the embedded interpreter. So, while it may see to accept a standard variable, command, or even a lambda, it ultimately ends up creating an internal tcl variable with that name, and associates that internal variable with the underlying tcl widget. If you do not use one of the special variables, it is going to be difficult for you to get or set the value of that variable.

For example, consider this set of commands:

```
var = tk.StringVar(value="hello")
tk.Button(root, textvariable=var)
```

When that code is run, the text that appears on the button will be `hello`. If you change the variable at any time (eg: `var.set("goodbye")`), the button will automatically be changed to show the new value.